# phpMyAdmin filling tables with random test data

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Is it possible for example to fill this table quickly that each country would have it's own id?:
`

```
CREATE TABLE Countries(
    CtID INT NOT NULL,
    CountryName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pks PRIMARY KEY(CtID)
);
```

I am suing phpmyadmin system, and have various tables without information so far, so was wondering do I have to fill everything by hand manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can export countries from here. [countries table](https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/sql.php?db=world&table=Country&pos=0)